# Spark/Pandas/SQL table Joins

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have below two dataframes and want to populate the final dataframe by joining two two input dataframes.

df1 i.e table1

```
id    | code | name | location  | val | date
1000  | 1    | 'A'  | 'AABB'    | 1   | 2021-01-01
1000  | 2    | 'B'  | 'BBCC'    | 3   | 2021-01-01
1000  | 3    | 'C'  | 'CCDD'    | 4   | 2021-01-01
1000  | 4    | 'D'  | 'DDEE'    | 1   | 2021-01-01
2000  | 1    | 'E'  | 'EEFF'    | 5   | 2021-03-01
2000  | 2    | 'F'  | 'XXYY'    | 4   | 2021-03-01
2000  | 3    | 'G'  | 'YYZZ'    | 2   | 2021-03-01
2000  | 4    | 'H'  | 'ZZAA'    | 1   | 2021-03-01
2000  | 4    | 'I'  | 'IIII'    | 1   | 2021-03-01

df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')
```

df2 i.e table2

```
id   | city | dist | state | count | tot_sum | date

1000 | null | null | null  | null  | null    | 2021-01-01
2000 | null | null | null  | null  | null    | 2021-03-01

df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')
```

df3 i.e table3

```
id   | city   | dist   | state  | count | tot_sum | date
1000 | 'AABB' | 'BBCC' | 'CCDD' | 1     |  9      | 2021-01-01
2000 | 'EEFF' | 'XXYY' | 'YYZZ' | 2     |  13     | 2021-03-01
```

**Logic:**

*when code =1 then consider location as city*

*when code =2 then consider location as dist*

*when code =3 then consider location as state*

*when code =4 then count the total number of records for that code for that id i.e in case of id 1000 we have only one record with code 4, in case of id 2000 we have 2 records*

*with code 4 sum of all vals for that id is the tot_sum i.e for id 1000 it will be 1+3+4+1=9, for id 2000 it will be 5+4+2+1+1=13*

trying something like below however it didn't work

```
select d2.id as id,
       d2.date as date,
       CASE WHEN d1.code=1 then d1.location else null end as city,
       CASE WHEN d1.code=2 then d1.location else null end as dist,
       CASE WHEN d1.code=3 then d1.location else null end as state
FROM   df1 d1 join df2 d2 on d1.id=d2.id 




select d2.id,
       d2.date
       CASE WHEN d1.code=1 then state=d1.location,
       CASE WHEN d1.code=2 then dist=d1.location,
       CASE WHEN d1.code=3 then CityName=d1.location
FROM   df1 d1 join df2 d2 on d1.id=d2.id
```

Any suggestions?

**Note:** Looking for a SQL Query(considering two input tables)/Pyspark dataframes/Pandas dataframes

[image]

***DF1:***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not really understand why you want to join with df2. All your data are already in df1, that's just an aggregation.

---

### Using SQL

```sql
select * from df2 inner join (
select id,
       first(case when code=1 then location end) as city,
       first(case when code=2 then location end) as dist,
       first(case when code=3 then location end) as state,
       count(case when code=4 then 1 end) as count,
       sum(val) as tot_sum,
       date
from df1 
group by id, date
) t on t.id = df2.id
```

---

### Using Pyspark

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df1.groupBy("id", "date").agg(
    F.first(F.when(F.col("code") == 1, F.col("location")),ignorenulls=True).alias("city"),
    F.first(F.when(F.col("code") == 2, F.col("location")),ignorenulls=True).alias("dist"),
    F.first(F.when(F.col("code") == 3, F.col("location")),ignorenulls=True).alias("state"),
    F.count(F.when(F.col("code") == 4, F.col("code"))).alias("count"),
    F.sum(F.col("val")).alias("tot_sum"),
)

df3 = df1.join(df2, on='id')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In DF1/Table1, I have a lot of other data which we don't want to final result set. I didn't give the complete df1/table1 dataset(It has 100's of columns, my interest is only in these 6 to 7 columns). That's why creating DF3. Hope it clears.

Comment: @data_addict well, once df1 properly created, you just join it to df2 on id... look at my edit. You drop in the select the empty df2 columns.

Comment: Tested the above, it's populating null values for dist, state, Attached the screenshot(In the question).  Any suggestions, please

Comment: @data_addict show df1 content ... probably you have a problem there.

Comment: Attached the screenshot of DF1 in the question, Can you check?

Comment: @data_addict sorry my bad. Forgot an option. See the edit

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
select d2.id as id,
       d2.date as date,
       max(CASE WHEN d1.code=1 then d1.location end) as city,
       max(CASE WHEN d1.code=2 then d1.location end) as dist,
       max(CASE WHEN d1.code=3 then d1.location end) as state,
       sum(CASE WHEN d1.code=4 then d1.val else 0 end) as cnt
from df1 d1 join
     df2 d2
     on d1.id=d2.id 
group by d2.id, d2.date;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you let me know how to populate tot_sum?

Comment: Able to populate tot_sum **` select d2.id as id,
       d2.date as date,
       max(CASE WHEN d1.code=1 then d1.location end) as city,
       max(CASE WHEN d1.code=2 then d1.location end) as dist,
       max(CASE WHEN d1.code=3 then d1.location end) as state,
       sum(CASE WHEN d1.code=4 then d1.val else 0 end) as cnt,
       sum(val) as tot_sum
from df1 d1 join
     df2 d2
     on d1.id=d2.id 
group by d2.id, d2.date`**, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the question, you wish to join df1 and df2 together.

Depending on which column you wish to use for this purpose (I am assuming ID), you can implement as follows in SQL:

```
select t1.id, t1.code, t1.name,
t1.location, t1.val, t1.date, 
t2.city, t2.dist, t2.state, 
t2.count, t2.tot_sum from df1 as t1 
inner join df2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
```

Comment: I want to join both tables on id column, however, join should be based on condition. As I mentioned in the logic, If code=1 then populate the city column, something on these notes needs to join the tables. It's not plain join. It's kind of flattening the results.